# Show date & time from database in html input field

Tags: python, html, django-templates

I wanted to show dates from my database in my HTML input field. For example id one has "2023-01-13 17:30:00", but when I display it on my input field it just show "Jan." I wanted it to display exactly as "2023-01-13 17:30:00". You might be confused why there is a submit button but has readonly input fields, it's for a condition where if the user is a not the admin, they can't edit the records.

**HTML file**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Title：</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value={{query.title}} readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description：</label>
            <input type="text" name="description" value={{query.description}} readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start time：</label>
            <input type="text" name="start_time" value={{query.start_time}} readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>End time：</label>
            <input type="text" name="end_time" value={{query.end_time}} readonly>
    </div>
    <div align="center" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def event_edit(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = Event.objects.get(id=id)
        return render(request, 'project/event_edit.html', {'query': query})
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Add your Event(models.Model) model code

Comment: Which type of output you want in html input ??

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala just a text output and in this format ,"2023-01-13 17:30:00" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template tag for date-time like this

```
<input type="text" name="end_time" value={{i.cr_date|date:"d-m-Y,H:i:s"}} readonly>
```

#### Browser Output

[image]

for more info visit [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/references/2016/06/21/date-filter.html)

Comment: this answers my problem, thank you!